# How can I post a facebook album photo to user's wall using graph api

Tags: facebook, api

I can use graph api to upload photo to facebook user's album and I can add new post with a image url to user's wall.

The problem is, if the image url is a photo that has been already uploaded to facebook, the add post graph api will return fail with following error:

```
FBCDN image is not allowed in stream
```

Is there a way that I can add wall post with the photo url/object_id that has already uploaded to the user's facebook album before?

Comment: Same problem.. Would be good to know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does not support this feature,you may want see this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/